# Parameter undefined in URL

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just started learning Angular and I am lost for this first application.
I'm looking to pass an ID to a child component so that it executes a request to an API to retrieve data.

Here is my code:

**Child component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-set-content',
  templateUrl: './set-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./set-content.component.css']
})
export class SetContentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() setId;
  equipments;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.equipments = this.http.get('https://myapi.com/sets/'+this.setId+'/details')
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**HTML Code for the Parent component:**

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let set of sets | async">
    <div class="card-header">
            {{ set.name }}
    </div>

    <div class="card-block">
        <div class="card-text">
                <app-set-content [setId]="set._id">
                </app-set-content>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

However, in my browser console, I see that the ID passed to the child component is "undefined".

```
GET https://myapi.com/sets/undefined/details 400 (Bad Request)
```

I tried to pass an arbitrary parameter like "1" but I get the same error

Comment: `Input` variables wont be defined during the component instantiation. See https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call in `ngOnInit` method because `@Input` parameters will be initialized ligecycle called `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.equipments = this.http.get('https://myapi.com/sets/'+this.setId+'/details')
}
```

Comment: @mamenejr I am glad to help you!